# Not updating using Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel

Why this code is not working, please help me.

```
public function update(Request $request, LocalLevel $localLevel)
    {
       $localLevel->update([
            'LocalLevelName'=>$request->locallevelenglish,
            'LocalLevelNameNepali'=>$request->locallevelname,
            'type'=>$request->type,
        ]);
        return back()->with('message','Local Level Infomation Updated Successfully');
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please provide the route definition that points to this action ... and what "is not working" about it (what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening)

Comment: @lagbox the route is working fine.. When I put dd($localLevel) this displays connection and table as none. What may be the reason?
Route Code
Route::resource('/prison/locallevel',LocalLevelController::class);

The data is not updating...

Comment: You are binging the model on your function `LocalLevel $localLevel` so `$localLevel` should be match with your model `LocalLevel`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for your Controller method should match the route parameter, `$locallevel` not `$localLevel`. When they don't match the router won't substitute the binding for your Implicit Route Model Binding; instead it will inject a dependency (a new instance of that model).